# in a console app is there a way to detect when an program is closed

Tags: javascript, console-application, activex

using IE , with javascript, i am calling a local program via

```
var ShellApp= new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var cmd= "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Folder\\SubFolder\\program.exe"; 
ShellApp.ShellExecute(cmd,"-o","","open","2");
```

this will be run on a local network, not by outside users or public or anything

is there any way to detect when that particular program is closed ?